# Android Application not running on Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

ive recently started developing a small android trivial game, when i go to run it on an emulator within Android studio , with the relevant SDK,  it installs onto the emulator without any errors.However when i try to open the app in the emulator, it says the game wont run 
I was just looking to see if anyone else had experienced this problem and what could be done to resolve it ?

Here is my code

Main Activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


List<Quiz> quizList;
int score = 0;
int qid = 0;
Quiz currentq;
TextView txtquestion;
RadioButton ra, rb, rc, rd;
Button bn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    QBD qbd = new QBD(this);
    quizList = qbd.getAllQuestions();
    currentq = quizList.get(qid);
    txtquestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
    ra = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.R1);
    rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.R2);
    rc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.R3);
    rd = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.R4);
    bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.N);
    setQuestionView();
    bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            RadioGroup rgr = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RG);
            RadioButton ans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rgr.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            if (currentq.getRA().equals(ans.getText())) {
                score++;
            }
            currentq = quizList.get(qid);
            setQuestionView();
        }
    });


}

private void setQuestionView() {
    txtquestion.setText(currentq.getQ());
    ra.setText(currentq.getA());
    rb.setText(currentq.getB());
    rc.setText(currentq.getC());
    rd.setText(currentq.getD());
    qid++;
}







}
```

XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">



     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text">


      </TextView>

      <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/RG"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/R1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="button"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/R2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="button"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/R3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="button"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/R4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="button"/>


    </RadioGroup>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/N"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"/>

 </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Database Help and Class
     package com.example.gregor.disseration2;

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class QBD extends  SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static  final int DATABASE = 1;
private static  final String DATABASE_NAME = "FUNWITHFLAGS";
private static  final String TABLE_FLAG ="flags";
private static  final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static  final String KEY_Q = "q";
private static  final String KEY_A = "a";
private static final  String KEY_B = "b";
private static final  String KEY_C = "c";
private static final  String KEY_D ="d";
private static final  String KEY_RA = "ra";
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public QBD(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE);


}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    database= db;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_FLAG + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_Q
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_RA+ " TEXT, "+KEY_A +" TEXT, "
            +KEY_B +" TEXT, "+KEY_C+" TEXT"+KEY_D+"TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    Quiz q1 = new Quiz("Which one of these flags has 52 Stars?", "USA", "UK", "Germany",
            "none of the above","A");
    this.addQuestionBank(q1);
    Quiz q2 = new Quiz("Which country has the St George Cross as it flags?", "USA", "England",
            "Jamaica ", "none of the above","B");
    this.addQuestionBank(q2);
    Quiz q3 = new Quiz("Which one of these countries does NOT have a tricolor?",
            "Italy", "UK", "Germany", "France","B");
    this.addQuestionBank(q3);
    Quiz q4 = new Quiz("Which one of these flags is NOT in the six nations?", "Tricolore",
            " il Tricolore", "Saltire", "Stars and Stripes","D");
    this.addQuestionBank(q4);
    Quiz q5 = new Quiz("What does a flag upside down s mean?", "Distress",
            " Safety", " A bit of drunken banter ", "None of the above","A");
    this.addQuestionBank(q5);

    db.close();
}




 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
  // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FLAG);
   // Create tables again
       onCreate(db);
     }


   public void addQuestionBank(Quiz quest){
    //  SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_Q,quest.getQ());
    values.put(KEY_RA,quest.getRA());
    values.put(KEY_A,quest.getA());
    values.put(KEY_B,quest.getB());
    values.put(KEY_C,quest.getC());
    values.put(KEY_D,quest.getD());
     database.insert(TABLE_FLAG,null,values);
  }
   public List<Quiz>getAllQuestions() {
      List<Quiz> quizl = new ArrayList<Quiz>();
     String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FLAG;
      database = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
      if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Quiz qz = new Quiz();
            qz.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            qz.setQ(cursor.getString(1));
            qz.setA(cursor.getString(2));
            qz.setB(cursor.getString(3));
            qz.setC(cursor.getString(4));
            qz.setD(cursor.getString(5));
            qz.setRA(cursor.getString(6));
            quizl.add(qz);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return quizl;
   }
   public int  rowcount(){
    int row = 0;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT *FROM" + TABLE_FLAG;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    row = cursor.getCount();
    return row;
}
```

}

```
public class Quiz{
   private int id;
   private String Q;
   private String A;
   private String B;
   private String C;
   private String D;
   private String RA;

public Quiz() {
    id = 0;
    Q = "";
    A = "";
    B = "";
    C = "";
    D = "";
    RA = "";

}


public Quiz(String q, String a, String b, String c, String d, String ra) {
    Q = q;
    A = a;
    B = b;
    C = c;
    D = d;
    RA = ra;

}


public int getID() {
    return id;

}
public String getQ()

{
    return Q;
}

public String getA()

{
    return A;
}



public String getB()

{
    return B;
}

public String getC()

{
    return C;
}

public String getD()

{
    return D;
}

public String getRA()

{
    return RA;
}

public void setID(int ID) {

    ID = id;
}

public void setQ(String q) {
    Q = q;
}

public void setA(String a) {
    A = a;

}

public void setB(String b) {
    B = b;

}

public void setC(String c) {
    C = c;

}

public void setD(String d) {
    D = d;

}

public void setRA(String ra) {
    RA = ra;

}
```

}

Comment: What are the code and logcat?

Comment: Logcat doesnt save anything but i will upload a screen shot in a minute

Comment: You can copy directly from it.

Comment: Okay, but it doesnt show any errors, of any kind, im really confused by this sorry

Comment: Do you think it could have anything to do with my gradle build ?

Comment: Sorry about the spamming but i just discovered theres some issue in regard to my database classes that are causing the issues